# Mock a class method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

i have an interface **IKeyValueStore** and i wanted to Mock this class and set its one method to return some dummy data. I have tried this way

```
  var storemock = new Mock<IKeyValueStore>();
  storemock.Setup(m => m.Restore<List<IProductDescription>>(It.IsAny<string>(),null,new StringDataContractSerializer())).Returns(ListOfProductDescriptions);

  private List<IProductDescription> ListOfProductDescriptions()
  {
     var obj1 = new ProductDescription("id1");
     var lst = new List<IProductDescription>();
     lst.Add(obj1);

     return lst;
  }
```

i am passing this storemock object to one of my testing class constructor. say **TestClass**

```
var objtestclass = new TestClass(storemock.Object);
```

and the i calling a method the call restore method.

```
objtestclass.checkstore();
```

during the constructor i am setting the **IkeyValueStore** type **_store** private field. So my testclass constructor is :-

```
public TestClass(IkeyValueStore store)
{
   _store = store;
}
```

My testing Method (restore) is :-

```
Public async Task<IEnumerable<IProductDescription>> checkscore()
{
   // here products is coming null.
   Products = _store.Restore<List<IProductDescription>>(CachedProductsKey, null, new StringDataContractSerializer());
}
```

**Problem** :- In checkstore method product should have a list of product descriptions but is coming null. Am i making a wrong mock of IkeyValueStore ? any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your problem is that the third argument is not getting matched correctly so your mock you set up is not being used.

In your setup instead of using `new StringDataContractSerializer()` try `It.IsAny<StringDataContractSerializer>()`

Comment: Exactly. It compares instance.

Comment: @Matthew That's the exact problem. Thanks :)